# Why does `md5sum` not give the same hash as the Internet does?

Tags: echo, hashsum

I want to find the md5 hash of the string "a", but running `echo "a" | md5sum` gives me another hash than what I get if I search the internet (for example using [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=md5%20a&ia=answer) or [the first search result I found](https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/)).

Running `echo "a" | md5sum` gives me "60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3", but it should be "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661".

If I make a reverse hash lookup for "60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3", I do however get "a".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason for the hashes being different is that `echo` includes a newline at the end of the output string to make it pretty. This can be prohibited by the `-n` flag (if your implementation of `echo` supports it), or by using another program (like `printf`):

```
> echo "a" | md5sum   
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  -

> echo -n "a" | md5sum
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -

> printf "a" | md5sum 
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -
```

Comment: `echo` adds a newline to the output to make it a complete line, not to make it pretty.

Comment: @Kusalananda Typing in `printf text` makes the text appear infront of the next prompt line.